# Linux - display or upgrade security updates only using apt

Tags: debian, security, apt, upgrade

is there a way to list or install security upgrades only using apt?

if I list upgrades with:

```
apt list --upgradable
```

can I also see **without knowing** packages and libraries which upgrades are relevant **security upgrades**.

and furthermore is there an option to only apply those by skipping any others, so the *non-security-relevant upgrades* would be prompted again next time I run `apt upgrade`?

Comment: so you have two questions, 1.print security updates, 2.update only selected packages, well I know that there are 6 links in sources.list and two of them are security related repo links, you can see which upgradable packages would be downloaded from each link by following command: **sudo apt upgrade --no-upgrade --assume-no --print-uris**

Comment: but about second question, apparently you can choose a single package to be upgraded by the following command **sudo apt upgrade --upgrade-only <package name>** but this doesn't work for me, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt` can’t (yet) provide the information you’re after. `aptitude` can though, albeit somewhat confusingly:

```
aptitude search '~U ~ODebian' -F "%p %O"|awk '/Debian-Security/ {print $1}'
```

This searches all upgradable (`~U`) packages from official Debian repositories (`~ODebian`), and displays their package name (`%p`) and “origin” (`%O`). The latter actually displays the repository *label*, which is “Debian-Security:9/stable” for the Debian 9 security repositories. You end up with a list of upgradable package names from the security repositories.

There are a variety of ways to install only security upgrades, none of them ideal though.

- `aptitude`’s text interface allows only security upgrades to be applied, simply by scrolling to the “Security Updates” header (which should be the first one) and hitting <kbd>+</kbd>.
- You can feed the list of packages extracted above to `apt` to install the upgrades:

  ```
  aptitude search '~U ~ODebian' -F "%p %O" |
  awk '/Debian-Security/ {print $1}' |
  xargs apt-get install --only-upgrade
  ```

  This has the unfortunate side-effect of clearing the “automatically installed” marker on upgraded packages.
- You can use [`unattended-upgrades`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/unattended-upgrades), whose default action is to only apply security upgrades:

  ```
  unattended-upgrades -v
  ```

  If you don’t want upgrades to be installed automatically, you’ll need to disable `unattended-upgrades`’s daily cron job.

Answer (score 6):

To display the security update you can use:

```
apt-get --just-print upgrade | grep -i security | awk '{print $2}' | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

To apply only the security updates for 1 package:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade pckg_name
```

To apply only the security updates from list:

```
list=$(apt-get --just-print upgrade | grep -i security | awk '{print $2}' | awk '!seen[$0]++')
apt-get install --only-upgrade $list
```