# Right way to get the list of installed packages matching a pattern?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm on system running a (fairly recent-)Debian-based distribution.

I'd like to generate a plain list of all installed packages matching a certain pattern. I can do that by, running, say,

```
apt list --installed "linux-image-*" | cut -d/ -f1
```

but I get lines I don't care for, e.g.:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Listing...
```

So maybe I'd better not use `apt`. I can run dpkg-query like so:

```
dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n' --show "linux-image*"
```

but that's not limited to installed packages. I could use

```
dpkg-query --list "linux-image-*" | grep "ii"
```

but then I'd need to do a bunch of text processing, and who can trust those spaces, right?

So, bottom line: What's the **right** way to get the list of installed packages matching a pattern?

---

**Note**:

- Bonus points if it can be a proper regexp rather than just a shell glob.
- Having to parse the text seems like a less-than-ideal solution; if that's what you suggest, please argue why there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 25):

```
$ apt list --installed "linux-image-*" 2>/dev/null |awk -F'/' 'NR>1{print $1}'
linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64
linux-image-4.11.0-1-amd64
linux-image-4.12.0-1-amd64
linux-image-4.13.0-1-amd64
linux-image-4.8.0-2-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-1-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-2-amd64
linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Talking about regex:

```
$ apt list --installed "linux-image-*" 2>/dev/null |awk -F'/' 'NR>1 && $0~/4.1/{print $1}'
linux-image-4.11.0-1-amd64
linux-image-4.12.0-1-amd64
linux-image-4.13.0-1-amd64
```

You can also use `dpkg-query` with `-f` (--showformat) option,which when  invoked without any package name, by default only installed packages are listed.

```
$ dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' -W |grep 'linux-image' #-W == --show
```

Comment: "add `|awk -F'/' 'NR>1{print $1}'` to apt list command" is possible shortest answer for "apt list only names"

Answer (score 13):

`aptitude` supports searching among all packages known to the package management tools, installed or otherwise, using regular expressions, without extraneous output, and can be told how to format its output:

```
aptitude search "linux-image-.*"
```

To list only installed packages:

```
aptitude search "linux-image-.* ~i"
```

To list only installed package *names* matching the regular expression:

```
aptitude search "linux-image-.* ~i" -F "%p"
```

The documentation covers [the available search patterns](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04.en.html) and [output format specifiers](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html) in detail. You’ll also find examples on this site, for example [is there a way to use regexp with aptitude?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298405/86440), [regexp with aptitude part 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335035/86440), and [Linux - display or upgrade security updates only using apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394438/86440).

Answer (score 11):

Here's one good way to do get the list of installed packages on a Debian-based system:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}'
```

The output lines of `dpkg -l` can be trusted to be sane.
The pattern `^ii` will match the lines of installed packages,
and the simple Awk will extract the second column,
the package names (the same names used in `apt-get install` commands).
Package names cannot contain whitespace,
so this again is a safe operation.

Comment: This works when you want to grep by version. The answers with `aptitude search` and `apt list` in this case don't.

Answer (score 3):

In order to "trap" the searched term when ***grep*** ping ***dpkg*** output, need to encase the search term as follows. "***git***" is used as the specimen search term:

```
dpkg -l |grep "^ii  git[[:space:]]"
```

The ***carat*** (^) ***ii*** followed by (2) spaces prepending the searched term ensures nothing **BEFORE** it other than that combination of characters can match.

The `[[:space:]]` abutting the searched term precludes partial matches from occurring by only matching spaces immediately **AFTER** it.